# Fetching and retrieving data from realtime database Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I encountered a problem while retrieving specific data from the firebase database, however, I was able to retrieve other data and view it using RecyclerView. The address and contact number is not showing. Here is my code and snippet of the output.

[lopdetails_items.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7QnM.png)
[Emulator Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJW8B.png)

**LopDetailsAdapter.java**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

public class LoPdetailsAdapter extends 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RegisterParking,LoPdetailsAdapter.myViewHolder> {
    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
    * @param options
    */
    public LoPdetailsAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RegisterParking> options) {
        super(options);
    }

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LoPdetailsAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RegisterParking model) {
    holder.loparkingname.setText(model.getLoparkingname());
    holder.lofullname.setText(model.getLofullname());
    holder.lorates.setText(model.getLorates());
    holder.lovtypes.setText(model.getLovtypes());
    holder.loallowed.setText(model.getLoallowed());
    holder.loparkingtype.setText(model.getLoparkingtype());
    holder.lopenalty.setText(model.getLopenalty());
    holder.lonumber.setText(model.getLonumber());
    holder.loaddress.setText(model.getLoaddress());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public LoPdetailsAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lopdetails_items,parent,false);
    return new LoPdetailsAdapter.myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView loparkingname, lofullname,  lorates, lovtypes, loallowed, loparkingtype, lopenalty, lonumber, loaddress;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        loparkingname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pname);
        lofullname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullNamelo);
        lonumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactnoLO);
        loaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.randomAddress);
        lorates = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Ratelo);
        lovtypes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Typeslo);
        loallowed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Numberlo);
        loparkingtype = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Ptypeslo);
        lopenalty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PRateslo);
    }
}
```

}

**LoParkingDetails.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class LoParkingDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

//parkingDetails
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LoPdetailsAdapter loPdetailsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lo_parking_details);

    toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //ParkingDetails
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.loD);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RegisterParking> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RegisterParking>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegParkingArea"), RegisterParking.class)
                    .build();

    loPdetailsAdapter = new LoPdetailsAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(loPdetailsAdapter);
}
//ParkingDetails
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    loPdetailsAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    loPdetailsAdapter.stopListening();
}
//Endpoint
```

**lopdetails_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
android:elevation="6dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Pname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parking Name:"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullNamelo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Pname"
        android:text="Landowner Fullname:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactnoLO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fullNamelo"
        android:text="Phone Number:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/randomAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/contactnoLO"
        android:text="Complete Address:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ratelo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/randomAddress"
        android:text="Parking Rates:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Typeslo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Ratelo"
        android:text="Types of vehicle allowed:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Numberlo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Typeslo"
        android:text="Number of allowed Vehicle:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ptypeslo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Numberlo"
        android:text="Type Parking type:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PRateslo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Ptypeslo"
        android:text="Penalty Rates:"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Also post your firebase structure please.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo